# Mocking a React component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

**Question 1**

According to [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react), we can mock a React component as follows:

```
jest.mock('./Chart', () => () => 'Chart');
```

As I understand it, the second parameter is a function, that returns a function component that renders a string. Why is the second parameter a function returning a function component (as opposed to simply a function component)?

**Question 2**

In an existing code base, I am seeing the mocking done this way:

```
jest.mock('./Chart', () => ({ Chart: 'mockChart' }));
```

In this case, the second parameter is a function component that returns an object. What is the intention here? Why do we not have a function returning a function component in this case? What is the intent of the function component returning an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second `jest.mock` parameter is [factory function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options). It should return a value that a module will be mocked with.

```
jest.mock('./Chart', () => () => 'Chart');
```

means that module exports are mocked with `() => 'Chart'` functional component.

```
jest.mock('./Chart', () => ({ Chart: 'mockChart' }));
```

means that module exports are mocked with `{ Chart: 'mockChart' }` object, i.e. `Chart` named export is mocked with `mockChart` string.